# Hover Tool for plots in Pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyside6

I want to have data information shown when hovering over a line in pyqtgraph plots, but can't get my `sigpointsHovered` to emit any signal. Here is a simple example of what i tried to do:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
import pyqtgraph as pg

def hovered(self, points, ev):
    print("FOOO")
    
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()

plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
plot_item = plot_widget.getPlotItem()
line = plot_item.plot(x,y)
line.sigPointsHovered.connect(hovered)

layout.addWidget(plot_widget)
window.setLayout(layout)
       
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I have already tried setting `"hoverable" = True` and read the docs several times, but I honestly have no clue why the `sigPointsHovered` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why `sigPointsHovered` is not working

In short: There is no way to set "hoverable" argument for `PlotDataItem` class's `ScatterPlotItem` right now. Therefore, it is not possible to use `sigPointsHovered`.

You could see this in the source code of `PlotDataItem` class's function `updateItems`.

[image]

### Workarounds

1. If you really want something like `sigPointsHovered` right now, instead of using a `PlotWiget`, use a `ScatterPlotItem` and set `hoverable = True` when you initialize it or when you use `setData` function. Run `python -m pyqtgraph.examples` and find the scatter plot example to see some example codes.
2. However, from your description, I think you actually want to do something when you hover over a "cruve" (instead of points). Currently, `PlotCurveItem` doesn't implement a `hoverEvent`, so you may try to make a class that inherits the `PlotCurveItem` and add a `hoverEvent` to it.

Let me show you how to do this.

In this example, when the cursor enters the curve, the color changes to blue, and turn back to white when it leave the curve.

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui


class HoverableCurveItem(pg.PlotCurveItem):
    sigCurveHovered = QtCore.Signal(object, object)
    sigCurveNotHovered = QtCore.Signal(object, object)

    def __init__(self, hoverable=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HoverableCurveItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.hoverable = hoverable
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def hoverEvent(self, ev):
        if self.hoverable:
            if self.mouseShape().contains(ev.pos()):
                self.sigCurveHovered.emit(self, ev)
            else:
                self.sigCurveNotHovered.emit(self, ev)


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.makeplot()

    def makeplot(self):
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        plot = self.view.addPlot()
        self.plotitem = HoverableCurveItem(x, y, pen=pg.mkPen('w', width=10))
        self.plotitem.setClickable(True, width=10)
        self.plotitem.sigCurveHovered.connect(self.hovered)
        self.plotitem.sigCurveNotHovered.connect(self.leaveHovered)
        plot.addItem(self.plotitem)

    def hovered(self):
        print("cursor entered curve")
        self.plotitem.setPen(pg.mkPen('b', width=10))

    def leaveHovered(self):
        self.plotitem.setPen(pg.mkPen('w', width=10))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

### Edit

Need to `setAcceptHoverEvent` to `True`

Also, in the updated example, when the cursor enters the curve, the color changes to blue, and turn back to white when it leave the curve.

Comment: Hello, I am really thankful for your help! So, you are completely right in your assumption of the hover tool, this is exactly what I want. Right now I tried to execute your workaround, but it did not print the "curve hovered" statement. For the scatterplot example I also tried them out and they are working - I was also thinking yesterday about switching to them, or maybe just draw both on the chart. Anyway, I think I get what your workaround intends to do, so many thanks for that input!

Comment: I edited the example, I hope this time it works for you. btw, please accept this as the correct answer.